# Numpy argsort behavior for equal numbers

Tags: python, numpy

array of odd length ( 15 ):

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
np.argsort(a)
```

**output = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]**

---

array of odd length ( 17 ):

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
np.argsort(a)
```

**output = [ 0 14 13 12 11 10  9 15  8  6  5  4  3  2  1  7 16]**

---

array of odd length ( 35 ):

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
np.argsort(a)
```

**output = [ 0 19 20 21 22 23 24 18 25 27 28 29 30 31 32 26 33 17 15  1  2  3  4  5  6
 16  7  9 10 11 12 13 14  8 34]**

---

---

array of even length (16):

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
    np.argsort(a)
```

**output = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]**

---

array of even length ( 18 ):

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
print len(a)
```

**output = [ 0 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 16 17]**

array of even length ( 36 ):

```
a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
np.argsort(a)
```

**output = [0 20 21 22 23 24 25 19 26 28 29 30 31 32 33 27 18 17 16  1  2  3  4  5  6
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 34 35]**

So would somebody explain me how this algorithm works in case of equal numbers ?

Comment: its random for identical numbers, use `kind='mergesort'` with it.

Comment: I did that many times and same numbers appears , so how its random ?

Comment: I guess we need to dig deep into `quicksort` implementation in it to find out.

Comment: For the default quicksort, unspecified behavior. The people who wrote the algorithm don't care, and if you care, you shouldn't pick quicksort.

Comment: @Divakar 'arbitrary' or 'undefined' would be better wording than 'random'

Comment: @Chris_Rands Totally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argsort()` uses a *configurable* sorting algorithm; you can pick between *quicksort*, *mergesort* or *heapsort*. From the [`argsort` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

> `numpy.argsort(a, axis=-1, kind='quicksort', order=None)`
>
> [...]
>
> **kind** : *{‘quicksort’, ‘mergesort’, ‘heapsort’}, optional*
>   Sorting algorithm.

The default is [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), and as Wikipedia states:

> In efficient implementations it is not a stable sort, meaning that the relative order of equal sort items is not preserved.

Numpy's implementation is efficient and it does not preserve the relative order of equal values.

If you need a stable sort, use [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) instead:

```
>>> a = np.array([5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5])
>>> np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort')
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34])
```

[Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) is not stable either.