# numpy cumulative count in linear time

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, cumulative-sum

I have data like this: `[144 144 144 144 143 143 143  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93]`, and I want to make data like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ....]`

I tried to use the function in the link below, I got this: `[3 2 1 0 2 1 0 9 0 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 8]`

How can I fix it?

```py
def grp_range(a):
    count = np.unique(a,return_counts=1)[1]
    idx = count.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(idx[-1],dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -count[:-1]+1
    out = id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(a).argsort()]

    return out
```

[How to use numpy to get the cumulative count by unique values in linear time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602269/how-to-use-numpy-to-get-the-cumulative-count-by-unique-values-in-linear-time)

Answer (score 2):

To speed up [bpfrd version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990264/17243882) you can use `numba`. On my machine ~40 times faster as [bpfrd version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990264/17243882) and **~10 times faster** to [ouroboros1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72991228/17243882) versions!

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_style(a):
    prev = a[0]
    idx = 0
    c = [idx]

    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i] == prev:
            idx += 1
        else:
            prev = a[i]
            idx = 0
        c.append(idx) 

    return np.array(c)
```

| Function | Timing (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each) |
| --- | --- |
| list_style | 818 µs ± 116 µs per loop |
| grp_range | 230 µs ± 81.3 µs per loop |
| cumcount | 170 µs ± 73.9 µs per loop |
| np_style_2 | 165 µs ± 86.2 µs per loop |
| np_style | 118 µs ± 79.3 µs per loop |
| **numba_style** | **19.2 µs ± 887 ns** per loop |

## Performance Testing

Speed comparison also to [ouroboros1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72991228/17243882) versions. Define functions:

```py
def list_style(a):
    prev = a[0]
    idx = 0
    c = [idx]

    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i] == prev:
            idx += 1
        else:
            prev = a[i]
            idx = 0
        c.append(idx) 

    return c

def dfill(a):
    n = a.size
    b = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(a[:-1] != a[1:])[0] + 1, [n]])
    return np.arange(n)[b[:-1]].repeat(np.diff(b))

def argunsort(s):
    n = s.size
    u = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int64)
    u[s] = np.arange(n)
    return u

def cumcount(a):
    n = a.size
    s = a.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    i = argunsort(s)
    b = a[s]
    return (np.arange(n) - dfill(b))[i]

def grp_range(a):
    count = np.unique(a,return_counts=1)[1]
    idx = count.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(idx[-1],dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -count[:-1]+1
    out = id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort').argsort()] # adjustment here
    return out

def np_style(a):
    unique, index, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True, return_index=True)
    arg_s = np.argsort(index)
    return np.concatenate(list(map(np.arange,counts[arg_s])), axis=0)

def np_style_2(a):
    aa = a+np.arange(len(a))
    unique, index = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
    for uni, ind in zip(unique, index):
        aa[a==uni] -= aa[ind]
    return aa
```

And the actual testing with a slightly longer array:

```py
n =   4,   3,  9, 15, 24, 100, 2500, 555
t = 144, 143, 93, 85, 84, 100, 250, 555
a = np.concatenate([[t_i]*n_i for t_i, n_i in zip(t,n)])

%timeit -n 3 -r 3 grp_range(a)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 np_style(a)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 np_style_2(a)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 cumcount(a)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 list_style(a)
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 numba_style(a)
```

Comment: Nice! Should be pointed out, however, that this solution only works for a list/array where each number has its own sequence (e.g. `[144, 143, 93]`). So, it will work for the example supplied by the OP, but if the sequences are mixed (e.g. `[144, 143, 93, 144, 93]`), this method will get you a very fast, but wrong, result.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a = [144, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93]
prev = a[0]
idx = 0
c = [idx]

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == prev:
        idx += 1
    else:
        prev = a[i]
        idx = 0
    c.append(idx) 

c
>[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** within your function change

```
out = id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(a).argsort()]
```

into

```
out = id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort').argsort()]
```

If speed is a concern, use the solution offered by @piRSquared in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602269/how-to-use-numpy-to-get-the-cumulative-count-by-unique-values-in-linear-time) mentioned. You'll need the first three functions mentioned. So:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([144, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93])

def dfill(a):
    n = a.size
    b = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(a[:-1] != a[1:])[0] + 1, [n]])
    return np.arange(n)[b[:-1]].repeat(np.diff(b))

def argunsort(s):
    n = s.size
    u = np.empty(n, dtype=np.int64)
    u[s] = np.arange(n)
    return u

def cumcount(a):
    n = a.size
    s = a.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    i = argunsort(s)
    b = a[s]
    return (np.arange(n) - dfill(b))[i]

cumcount(arr) # will get you desired output
```

---

The accepted answer from the referenced post is actually incorrect.

The problem lies with the fact that [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) uses *quicksort* as the default sorting algorithm. For a stable sort, we need *mergesort* (see the comments by @MartijnPieters on the matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440621/numpy-argsort-behavior-for-equal-numbers)).

So, in your slightly adjusted function we need:

```
import numpy as np

def grp_range(a):
    count = np.unique(a,return_counts=1)[1]
    idx = count.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(idx[-1],dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -count[:-1]+1
    out = id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(a, kind='mergesort').argsort()] # adjustment here
    return out
```

Testing a couple of examples:

```
# OP's example
arr = np.array([144, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93])

arr_result = grp_range(arr)
print(arr_result)
# [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] (correct)

# OP's example, with mixed sequence (note addition 143, 144 at arr1[9:11])
arr_alt = np.array([144, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 93, 93, 143, 144, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93])

arr_alt_result = grp_range(arr_alt)
print(arr_alt_result)
# [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 3 4 2 3 4 5 6 7] (correct) (note: arr_alt_result[9:11] == array([3, 4], dtype=int32))
```

As mentioned above, the solution offered by @piRSquared will be faster than this with the same results.

---

A final aside. The sequence posted is in descending order. If this is true for the actual data you are working with, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([144, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93])

count = np.unique(arr,return_counts=1)[1][::-1] # from ascending to descending
out = np.concatenate(list(map(np.arange,count)), axis=0)

# out: [0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

or this:

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [144, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93]
count_dict = Counter(arr)

out = list()
for v in count_dict.items():
    out.extend([*range(v[1])])
```

or indeed, use the answer provided by @bpfrd.